# itext7 - 'Pkcs12Store' exists in BouncyCastle.Crypto and BouncyCastle.Cryptography in c#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, itext7

**Issue with iText7 PDF Signing in C#**

I am encountering the following exception while trying to sign a PDF using iText7 version 8.0.2 in C#. I have also installed the `itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter` version 8.0.2 package.

Here is my code:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Signatures;
using itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser;
using itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parse.Listener;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using System.IO;
using iText.Bouncycastle.Cert;
using iText.Bouncycastle.X509;
using iText.Bouncycastle.Crypto;
using iText.Commons.Bouncycastle.Cert;
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

PdfReader reader1=new PdfReader(input);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader1);
IExternalSignature _privateSignature;
IX509Certificate[] _signChain;
string KEYSTORE = @"";
char[] PASSWORD = "".ToCharArray();

(I am receving error for below line)
var pks = new Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(KEYSTORE,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), PASSWORD);

string alias = null;

foreach (string tAlias in pks.Aliases)
{
     if (pks.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
     {
       alias = tAlias;break;
     }
}

var pk = pks.GetKey(alias).Key;
var ce = pks.GetCertificateChain(alias);
_signChain = new IX509Certificate[ce.Length];

for (int k = 0; k< ce.Length; ++k)
_signChain[k] = new X509CertificateBC(ce[k].Certificate);

_privateSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(new PrivateKeyBC(pk), "SHA-512");
using (FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();                                                           
     var signer = new iText.Signatures.PdfSigner(pdfReader, signedPdf, properties.UseAppendMode());
     PdfSignatureAppearance sap = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
     sap.SetLayer2Text(string.Empty);
     sap.SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
     sap.SetLayer2Text(DateTime.Now.ToString());
     sap.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
     sap.SetLayer2FontSize(7);
     sap.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(50, 700, 200, 100));
     PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
     sap.SetLayer2Font(font);
     signer.SignDetached(_privateSignature, _signChain, null, null, null, 0, iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

Error occured is :`The type 'Pkcs12Store' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942' and 'BouncyCastle.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=072edcf4a5328938'`

I have gone through from various post, but did not get anything. Please guide me to resolve above error

Comment: You seems to have referenced two different versions of Bouncycastle. You must resolve that conflict. We can't help to much when we don't know where the second one is coming from. bouncy-castle-adapter seems to reference BouncyCastle.Cryptography but something from your project references BouncyCastle.Crypto.

Comment: @Ralf Thank you for your reply. I have added only the packages, namely itext and bouncy-castle-adapter, both with version 8.0.2. I don't understand why it is pointing to Bouncy.crypto. Please guide me on how to check and resolve this issue.